# How do I create a synthetic cosine wave with changing amplitude and phase?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a cosine wave on numpy that changes with amplitude and phase over time?
How might I do that?

I have this so far, but the amplitude nor phase is changing over time:

```
east_sine = np.zeros((50,50))
sine = np.zeros((50))

for t in range(50):
    for x in range(50):
        sine[x] = np.sin(20*x*np.pi/100 - .1*t) 
        east_sine[t,:] = sine
```

Comment: You assign the reference to the same array to all east_sine[t]

Comment: would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @alagnak32 - if it is a cosine wave you want to generate, why are you using np.sin instead of np.cos?

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific with your questions.

If you want to have time-dependent amplitude and phase, you need define the sine in the form:

```
sine = A(t) * sin(a*x - b(t)*t)
```

For example, where `A(t) = t` and `b(t) = 0.1  t**2`:

```
x = np.linspace(0,50,1000)
t = np.linspace(0,10,1000)

sine =  t * np.sin(x - 0.1*np.square(t)*t)
```

[image]